# Generated constructor AST types

Tags: scala, types, abstract-syntax-tree

If you run SBT or REPL with `-Xprint:typer` flag and give it something basic like `object trees` or `class trees` you'll presumably get this output:

```
package <empty> {
  class trees extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): trees = {
      trees.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

In case of `object` the return type would be `trees.type`, but what is interesting is the type of the result, which is `Unit` for `()`, i.e:

```
def <init>(): trees = { // <- expect type trees
  trees.super.<init>();
  () // <- Should be of type Unit
}
```

Clearly if it's generated by the compiler itself and working it's correct, but why and how is it supposed to work?